# How to have optional blocks in an objective-c class?

Tags: objective-c, exception, objective-c-blocks

I have a class which I want to two optional blocks

so in the class.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^onConnectBlock)(void);
```

and in a method inside the class:

I have:

```
_onConnectBlock();
```

Unfortunately if this is not set:

```
[class setOnConnectBlock:^{
    [class send:auth];
}];
```

the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

I have tried to add an exception block but still returns `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

```
@try {
    _onCloseBlock();
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (self.onCloseBlock){
   _onCloseBlock();
}
```